# Why are some system functions undefined in Cygwin when using gcc -std=c++11?

Tags: c++11, gcc, include, cygwin, system

A program can fail to compile in Cygwin using `gcc -std=c++11`. Headers compile OK (unless, like boost/asio.hpp, they try to use a missing definition). Now, because Cygwin's `#ifdef` macros bypass some function definitions in the c++11 environment, a programs might not. This does not occur when the same source files are similarly compiled on Fedora Linux.

This example program fails to compile using the gcc -std=c++11 option:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main() { return 0; }
```

I first encountered this by discovering that the above program didn't compile, and then found even more similar problems when recompiling existing code using the updated standard.

The include sections I've found to be broken are listed in the reply.

[edited to correct typos.]

Comment: Why aren't you using `-std=gnu++11` instead?

Comment: Thanks @MarkGlisse. I used the `c++11` option I found in the documentation. I didn't realize there was another way of specifying the new standard until you pointed it out.(Your method is better. The problem won't recur when you upgrade or reinstall boost.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround you can use until the Cygwin include library is updated:

In your source code, include

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

before any other includes. This workaround is not needed in Fedora Linux, only in the Cygwin environment and then only with the -std= compiler option.

This fixes:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp> // (Because it uses sigfillset from sys/signal.h)
#include <sys/signal.h>   // sigfillset and others declared nearby
#include <sys/types.h>    // u_int and other __MISC_VISIBLE typedefs
#include <stdio.h>        // at least fileno
#include <string.h>       // at least strdup
```

and possibly other glitches I haven't discovered. This could also be fixed by simply modifying `/usr/include/sys/features.h`, adding

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE // LOCAL WORK-AROUND
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
```

near the beginning of the file. While this works for casual library users, it's not the method Cygwin developers will use.

Comment: _GNU_SOURCE is the default.  Why using `gcc -std=c++11` ? Or is C or is C++ , I do not understand calling the c ompiler with a C++ standard.

Comment: It turns out that I **was** actually using `c++ -std=c++11`. However, the same failure occurs whether using gcc, c++, or g++. If you google "gnu c++ compiler," gcc is what comes up. It is a c++ compiler.

Comment: /usr/bin/gcc and /usr/bin/g++ are two different compilers for two different languages. They are related, as the languages are related, but not identical. It is not clear to me if you have tested or not without `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 1):

Use `-std=gnu++11` instead of `-std=c++11` with Cygwin.

With Cygwin I've found `-std=c++11` seems to exclude GNU extensions and causes all kinds of issues with Boost and POSIX headers.